# how to store huge strings in python

Tags: python

I have to store huge string of size around 100 million bytes and more.How to handle this in python?

Comment: Why can't you google "python mmap" yourself?

Comment: Bigger lesson to learn there: Google is probably the best tool in your toolbox.

Comment: It was said many times, that `let me google that for you` is not the right answer on SO. If this question is duplicate, it should be closed. If not, then either providing a direct link to a good example or an example should be provided for such answers.

Comment: "let me google that for you" is the answer if you have not done basic research before asking on SO yourself - especially when the official documentation is found with the first hit and explaining the solution in depth and with examples - everything else is LAZYNESS

Answer (score 4):

1 million bytes is not a huge string in modern terms: 1 thousand million bytes is still manageable. Just use a string and stop trying to pre-optimise your code.

Comment: I agree, (I just need to learn to be quicker typer ;-). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That size string is not what one easily calls `huge`! Have you tried to use it? Why you belive that you need `mmap`?